# How do I get Code to auto switch to the code in the current branch?

Tags: git

I'm just looking to figure out why Code doesn't change the code in  my editor when I switch the branch in my terminal. Is there some plugin I need?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't said which editor you're using.  If it's Emacs, set `magit-auto-revert-mode`.

Comment: What is Code? Visual Studio Code? How did you "switch the branch" in your terminal? What command/s did you enter?

Answer (score 0):

Your didn't say what editor was used.
If you didn't commit before you had changed a branch. You merged changing into the branch, which is activated. And It's a bad practice...
Before you change branches, you can use command:

```
git stash
```

It helps you hide changings and save their.
After you changed the branch, manipulated there and decided to come back you can return your saved and hided code:

```
git stash pop
```